# How can I get docker running in Jenkins nodes which are containers?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

I am trying to get docker running on Jenkins which itself is a container. Below is part of the Pod spec.

`cyrilpanicker/jenkins` is an image with Jenkins and docker-cli installed.
For Docker daemon, I am running another container with `docker:dind` image (The nodes are running on a k8s cluster).
And to get `docker.sock` linked between them, I am using volume mounts.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: jenkins
      image: cyrilpanicker/jenkins
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
          name: docker-socket
    - name: docker
      image: docker:dind
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
          name: docker-socket
  volumes:
    - name: docker-socket
      hostPath:
        path: /docker.sock
        type: FileOrCreate
```

But this is not working. Below are the logs from the `docker` container.

```
time="2021-06-04T20:47:26.059792967Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
time="2021-06-04T20:47:26.061956820Z" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy
```

Can anyone suggest another way to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the kubernetes docs, `hostPath` mounts a path from node filesystem, so if I understand correctly, this is not what you want to achieve.
I'm afraid that it isn't possible do mount single file as a volume, so even if you remove `hostPath` from `volumes`, `docker.sock` will be mounted as directory:

```
jenkins@static-web:/$ ls -la /var/run/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun  5 14:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun  5 14:44 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 14:44 docker.sock
```

I would try to run docker daemon in dind container with TCP listener instead of sock file:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: jenkins
      image: cyrilpanicker/jenkins
    - name: docker
      image: docker:dind
      command: ["dockerd"]
      args: ["-H", "tcp://127.0.0.1:2376"]
      ports:
        - containerPort: 2376
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
```

```
jenkins@static-web:/$ docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376 ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

And then configure jenkins to use `tcp://127.0.0.1:2376` as a remote docker daemon.

Comment: You can mount a single file as a volume

Comment: this solution worked. and i was able to connect to the remote docker daemon using `docker.withServer('tcp://127.0.0.1:2376') {}` in Jenkinsfile